# Using VB or VBA To Get JSON Responds from Http Request

Tags: json, vba, http, ms-access, xmlhttprequest

I just posted my issue with HTTP GET Request using VBA, and I just got it working with the suggestion given to me in a previous post.  I took the "Basic" out of the "SetRequestHeader" and I was able to see data.  Since my data is in JSON format, I must request the data correctly and storage it to a text file.

In my code, I was setting P = JSON.parse(XMLHttpReq.responseText) being undefine, and what should I define JSON to be in this code???  I was not able to run it because of this issue.

Let me know if anyone see anything wrong too with this, or other suggestions!

I have added some VBA code below to handle the request.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sUrl As String, sAuth As String
    Dim P As Object
    Dim XMLHttpReq As MXXML2.ServerXMLHTTP

    sUrl = "https://api.ngs.nfl.com/tracking/game/play?gameKey=57444&playId=51"
    sAuth = "NGS AKIAIX2CQ7IEOKPOTKDQ:uNniaOp4jH8jcK9i/EtQhurlilc="

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic " & sAuth
        .send

        If XMLHttpReq.ReadyState = 4 Then
             If XMLHttpReq.Status = 200 Then

                  ' Process the JSON response here

                  Debug.Print "200 received"
                  Set P = JSON.parse(XMLHttpReq.responseText)
             Else
                  If XMLHttpReq.Status = 404 Then
                       ' Handle it
                  End If
             End If

        Debug.Print .getAllResponseHeaders
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: If you need to convert the data into 2d array or display it on the sheet then take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51147537/2165759).

Answer (score 1):

For the response I get, which is unauthorised, I used [JSONConverter](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas) and converted the response text into a JSON object. For the response I got I then show how to access the message returned.

Note: You need to add the  JSONConverter .bas to the project and then go VBE > Tools >References and add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub Test()
    Dim sUrl As String, sAuth As String

    Dim XMLHttpReq As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

    sUrl = "https://api.ngs.nfl.com/tracking/game/play?gameKey=57444&playId=51"
    sAuth = "NGS AKIAIX2CQ7IEOKPOTKDQ:uNniaOp4jH8jcK9i/EtQhurlilc="

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", sAuth
        .send

        Dim P As Object, key As Variant
        Set P = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
        WriteTextFile .responseText
        For Each key In P.Keys
            Debug.Print key & " : " & P(key)
        Next key
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub WriteTextFile(ByVal htmlResponse As String)
    Dim fso As Object, f As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\User\Desktop\info.txt", True, True)
    f.Write htmlResponse
    f.Close
End Sub
```

---

**Edit:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim sUrl As String, sAuth As String, XMLHttpReq As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
    sUrl = "https://api.ngs.nfl.com/tracking/game/play?gameKey=57444&playId=51"
    sAuth = "NGS AKIAIX2CQ7IEOKPOTKDQ:uNniaOp4jH8jcK9i/EtQhurlilc="

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sUrl, False
        .setRequestHeader "Authorization", sAuth
        .send
        WriteTextFile .responseText, "C:\Users\User\Desktop\info.txt"
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub WriteTextFile(ByVal htmlResponse As String, ByVal fileName As String)
    Dim fso As Object, f As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fso.CreateTextFile(fileName, True, True)
    f.Write htmlResponse
    f.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: You indicated errors, you are correct.  I took out the key word "Basic" from the .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", sAuth             That was the key to get results.   I See the results when I do a Debug.Print ResponseText.      The data that I see look like this:     31:13.800","x":34.22,"y":46.31,"z":0,"s":0,"a":0,"dis":0,"o":1.61,"dir":294.06,"isOnField":true},{"time":"2017-12-17T01:31:13.900","x":34.22,"y":46.32,"z":0,"s":0,"a":0,"dis":0,"o":1.62,"dir":294.85,"isOnField":true},      I am continuing

Comment: My previous comment was example of what I got from using the Debug.Print ResponseText       Is there a way without using JSON to get all of the data and have it on a file???      That will work for me,  I just like to copy and paste them into txt files.   I did this manually connecting and copying from the response body window.   The data I see is not from the start.   What do you recommend?   Is there a way to get the start and all of the content??   Or must I get small groups at a time??       I have also downloaded VBA-JSON V2.3.0  Is this the version you used?

Comment: Can you assist me with writing the output to text file??   Or must I create a new post???    Thank You

Comment: I have added an example of writing out to a text file. You could modify the bottom sub to accept a second argument which could be the save as filename as opposed to  the hard coded current filename.

Comment: Did that make sense?

Comment: Where do I put the Call to the WriteTextFile ???    Can it be where we Dim P as Object???    Can I call it from there (assuming taking the JSON stuff out)??     Thank You !!!!

Comment: See bottom version.

Comment: The system indicated that I don't have enough repts yet.    I do appreciate your help.    I will try playing with it now.   Let you know more later.     Thank You !!!!

Comment: I got the txt to work, and it all combined.    I will try to see if I can get it into something I can use.   If not, I will implement the JSON format.   I will let you know.

Comment: I encountered a problem using the VBA-JSON code.  The original declaration  Dim HMLHttpReq As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60    60 doesn't exit for me, but 30 does.    So I  did   Dim HMLHttpReq As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP30      The code runs and I get "wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" error for the Debug.Print key & " : " & P(key) .      I checked the WriteTextFile .ResponseText does have data.  It is just text data like when I did the first text test.    I also noticed that I do have the Module JsonConverter in my project.   It has the VBA code in there.    Suggestions? Thank U

Comment: Hi, if you have a question for me please ask it here in the comments. If it is additional information edit it into the question. If it is an answer,  post as an answer. Please don't add it as an edit to my answer. Others won't see it and be able to help you and it will confuse future readers of this answer. :-)