# how to display my JSON object in good format in VBA Excel

Tags: json, excel, vba

I know display my Parse Json in cell Excel when the Json is "simple" (when it's just string inside) but now i have String, object and array and i'm a little lost..
my json is following:

```
[
    {
        "name": null,
        "type": null,
        "actions": [],
        "screen": null,
        "container": null,
        "sysid": 5,
        "uftitem": null
    },
    {
        "name": null,
        "type": null,
        "actions": [],
        "screen": null,
        "container": null,
        "sysid": 6,
        "uftitem": null
    },
    {
        "name": "UTProject5",
        "type": "type",
        "actions": [
            {
                "name": "UTProject",
                "description": "UTProject",
                "pattern": "UTProject",
                "isCheck": true,
                "sysid": 1,
                "uftaction": {
                    "sysid_uftAction": 2,
                    "code": "code uft",
                    "maxTime": 10,
                    "nbCycle": 20
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "UTProject2",
                "description": "UTProject",
                "pattern": "UTProject",
                "isCheck": true,
                "sysid": 3,
                "uftaction": {
                    "sysid_uftAction": 4,
                    "code": "code uft",
                    "maxTime": 10,
                    "nbCycle": 20
                }
            }
        ],
        "screen": {
            "name": null,
            "type": null,
            "actions": [],
            "screen": null,
            "container": null,
            "sysid": 5,
            "uftitem": null
        },
        "container": {
            "name": null,
            "type": null,
            "actions": [],
            "screen": null,
            "container": null,
            "sysid": 6,
            "uftitem": null
        },
        "sysid": 7,
        "uftitem": {
            "code": "code",
            "parentCode": "tooooz",
            "sysid": 8
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "UTProject6",
        "type": "type",
        "actions": [
            {
                "name": "UTProject",
                "description": "UTProject",
                "pattern": "UTProject",
                "isCheck": true,
                "sysid": 1,
                "uftaction": {
                    "sysid_uftAction": 2,
                    "code": "code uft",
                    "maxTime": 10,
                    "nbCycle": 20
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "UTProject2",
                "description": "UTProject",
                "pattern": "UTProject",
                "isCheck": true,
                "sysid": 3,
                "uftaction": {
                    "sysid_uftAction": 4,
                    "code": "code uft",
                    "maxTime": 10,
                    "nbCycle": 20
                }
            }
        ],
        "screen": {
            "name": null,
            "type": null,
            "actions": [],
            "screen": null,
            "container": null,
            "sysid": 5,
            "uftitem": null
        },
        "container": {
            "name": null,
            "type": null,
            "actions": [],
            "screen": null,
            "container": null,
            "sysid": 6,
            "uftitem": null
        },
        "sysid": 9,
        "uftitem": {
            "code": null,
            "parentCode": null,
            "sysid": 10
        }
    }
]
```

I would like to access to what I want and display it in cell, but I don't know access in array and object.

Thanks every one!

Answer (score 6):

**General:**

You can empty the whole thing with the following code which makes use of [JSON converter](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas):

---

**Note:**

I am reading JSON string in from sheet and storing in object via `JSONConverter`. The initial object is a collection. I loop that collection and every nested level within using `TypeName` function* to determine what object(s) are stored at each level. I then use `Select Case` to handle these objects appropriately.

More efficient would be to design a re-usuable class to handle this. I have seen some other questions on SO where this is done.

<sub>* [VarType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/vartype-function) is actually more robust</sub>

---

**Example JSON**

[image: Example JSON]

---

**Example code output to immediate window:**

You can choose how you write to the cell by replacing the `Debug.Print` statements with assignments to sheet ranges.

[image: Sample code output]

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfoFromSheet()
    Dim jsonStr As String
    jsonStr = [A1]                               '<== read in from sheet
    Dim json As Object
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonStr)

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, key As Variant
    For i = 1 To json.Count
        For Each key In json(i).keys
            Select Case key
            Case "name", "type"
                Debug.Print key & " " & json(i)(key)
            Case Else
                Select Case TypeName(json(i)(key))
                Case "Dictionary"
                    Dim key2 As Variant
                    For Each key2 In json(i)(key)
                        Select Case TypeName(json(i)(key)(key2))
                        Case "Collection"
                            Dim k As Long
                            For k = 1 To json(i)(key)(key2).Count
                                Debug.Print key & " " & key2 & " " & json(i)(key)(key2)(k)
                            Next k
                        Case Else
                            Debug.Print key & " " & key2 & " " & json(i)(key)(key2)
                        End Select
                    Next key2
                Case "Collection"
                    For j = 1 To json(i)(key).Count '<== "actions"
                        Dim key3 As Variant
                        For Each key3 In json(i)(key)(j).keys
                            Select Case TypeName(json(i)(key)(j)(key3))
                            Case "String", "Boolean", "Double"
                                Debug.Print key & " " & key3 & " " & json(i)(key)(j)(key3)
                            Case Else
                                Dim key4 As Variant
                                For Each key4 In json(i)(key)(j)(key3).keys
                                    Debug.Print key & " " & key3 & " " & key4 & " " & json(i)(key)(j)(key3)(key4)
                                Next key4
                            End Select
                        Next key3
                    Next j
                Case Else
                    Debug.Print key & " " & json(i)(key)
                End Select
            End Select
        Next key
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

**tl;dr; Tutorial spot:**

So the above might have been a bit full on as it gets everything without lots of explanation. Below, we take a more detailed look at how to target some of that JSON and ***"talk"*** through the associated VBA.

For this you can use an online JSON parser to view the structure of your `JSON` more clearly. I posted your `JSON` string into [Json Parser Online](http://json.parser.online.fr/), and then examined the structure in the `String/parseJS eval`; left hand side section. There are other tools available.

The initial thing to note is the beginning `"["`.  The very first one you can see below.

[image: Start]

This denotes the `Collection` object, which is your `JSON` string when converted with `JsonConverter`. Everything else is nested between this opening `"["` bracket and its closing counterpart at the very end.

The next thing to note is that this is a collection of dictionaries, so everything that forms a "group" within, is a dictionary.

[image: Dictionary]

See the `"{"` denoting the start of the dictionary?

The dictionary has keys of `"name","type","actions"` etc.

An initial observation is that lots of this info is empty ie. `null`.
We can ignore these with an `IsNull` test (I choose to do this based on `"name"` field):

```
If Not IsNull(json(i)("name"))
```

We can also see that `"actions"`, in dictionaries where the `"name"` is not `null`, contains another collection of dictionaries. You see we have the `"["` followed by the `"{"` as described before.

[image: Collection of dictionaries]

We can see that each inner dictionary has keys of `"name", "description"` etc. We can also see that their values are of different datatypes.

Observing `"actions"` in the `JSON` structure, you can see these are (using an example dictionary):

1. String  `"name":"UTProject"`
2. String `"description":"UTProject"`
3. String "`pattern":"UTProject"`
4. Boolean `"isCheck":true`
5. Double `"sysid":1`
6. Dictionary `"uftaction" 'keys of ==> "sysid_uftAction":2,"code":"code uft","maxTime":10,"nbCycle":20`

So, we can use `Select Case` to handle the data type by testing with `TypeName`

For the primitive boolean, string and double data types we can simply print them by using the key e.g.

```
json(i)("actions")(j)("isCheck")
```

That will be a boolean result of `True` or `False.` `i` and `j` being indices of current position in loops of both outer and inner collections.

For the dictionary `"uftaction"`, we can loop over its keys:

```
For Each key2 In json(i)("actions")(j)(key).keys 
    Debug.Print "actions " & key & " " & key2 & " " & json(i)("actions")(j)(key)(key2)
Next key2
```

You could of course access with the name of the key without the loop over the keys at the end, e.g.:

```
json(i)("actions")(j)(key)("maxTime")
```

And throughout you could access specific positions via index rather than looping such that `i` and `j` would be replaced directly with a numeric value. And `key, key2` etc could be replaced by the actual literal string for any given *key*.

Hopefully that has given you some more insight.

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfoFromJSON()
    Dim jsonStr As String
    jsonStr = [A1]                               '<== read in from sheet
    Dim json As Object, i As Long
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(jsonStr) '<==This is a collection verified by Debug.Print TypeName(JSON)
    For i = 1 To json.Count
        If Not IsNull(json(i)("name")) Then
            'ignore the null names which have sys id only populated
            Debug.Print "name" & " " & json(i)("name")
            Debug.Print "type" & " " & json(i)("type")
            Dim j As Long
            For j = 1 To json(i)("actions").Count 'actions are a collection of dictionaries
                Dim key As Variant
                For Each key In json(i)("actions")(j).keys 'dictionary
                    'observing actions in the JSON structure you can see there are:
                    '                    String  "name":"UTProject"
                    'String "description":"UTProject",
                    'String "pattern":"UTProject",
                    'Boolean "isCheck":true,
                    'Double "sysid":1,
                    'Dictionary "uftaction" '==> "sysid_uftAction":2,"code":"code uft","maxTime":10,"nbCycle":20
                    'So we can use Select Case to handle the data type by testing with TypeName
                    Select Case TypeName(json(i)("actions")(j)(key))
                    Case "String", "Boolean", "Double" '<==good to go nothing extra needed
                        Debug.Print "actions " & key & " " & json(i)("actions")(j)(key)
                    Case Else                    ' we are dealing with uftaction which we know is a dictionary
                        Dim key2 As Variant
                        For Each key2 In json(i)("actions")(j)(key).keys '<==We know now we are looping the uftaction dictionary which has keys "sysid_uftAction","code","maxTime","nbCycle"
                            Debug.Print "actions " & key & " " & key2 & " " & json(i)("actions")(j)(key)(key2)
                        Next key2
                    End Select
                Next key
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice post. very thorough, and VBA+JSON has such limited resources, this something like this will be useful to many

Answer (score 1):

I create this simple function to formatt the Json string, if someone needed. The code is very simple.

```
Public Function indentJson(ByVal jsonIn As String) As String

Dim posizioneIndent As Integer
Dim contatore As Integer
Dim lungheza As Integer
Dim JsonOut As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim carattere As String


JsonOut = ""
lunghezza = Len(jsonIn)
contatore = 1
posizioneIndent = -1
carattere = ""

While contatore <> lunghezza + 1
        
    carattere = Mid(jsonIn, contatore, 1)
    
  If carattere = "{" Or carattere = "[" Then
    
     JsonOut = JsonOut & carattere
   JsonOut = JsonOut & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
     posizioneIndent = posizioneIndent + 1
     For i = 0 To posizioneIndent
     JsonOut = JsonOut & Space(5)
     Next i

  ElseIf carattere = "}" Or carattere = "]" Then
     JsonOut = JsonOut & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
     posizioneIndent = posizioneIndent - 1
     For i = 0 To posizioneIndent
      JsonOut = JsonOut + Space(5)
     Next i
     JsonOut = JsonOut + carattere
     'For i = 0 To posizioneIndent
     ' JsonOut = JsonOut + Space(5)
     'Next i

  ElseIf carattere = "," Then
JsonOut = JsonOut & carattere
JsonOut = JsonOut & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
For i = 0 To posizioneIndent
JsonOut = JsonOut + Space(5)
Next i

  Else
   JsonOut = JsonOut + carattere

End If

contatore = contatore + 1

Wend

indentJson = JsonOut

End Function
```

This is the result , in my case i put it in a textbox, If someone have a advice to improve, please tell me.

```
{
     "routingResponse":{
          "currentTimeUTC":"2022-10-16-09.16.48.012243+02:00",
          "executionMessage":{
               "code":0,
               "severity":"INFO",
               "codeDesc":"",
               "message":""
          },
          "arrivalTerminal":"031",
          "arrivalDepot":"031",
          "deliveryZone":"20",
          "consigneeZIPCode":"95024",
          "consigneeCity":"ACIREALE",
          "consigneeProvinceAbbreviation":"CT"
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, however the question is not really about indenting JSON, it's more about retrieving a specific value inside the JSON string. The question states at the end: "I would like to access to what I want [inside the JSON] and display it in cell". I think it would be better to make a self-answered question to post this information.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I do it:

```
Public Function indentJsonV2(ByVal jsonIn As String) As String
    Dim positionIndent As Double: positionIndent = -1
    Dim counter As Double: counter = 1
    Dim theLength As Double: theLength = Len(jsonIn)
    Dim JsonOut As String: JsonOut = vbNullString
    Dim i As Double: i = 0
    Dim theChar As String: theChar = vbNullString
    Dim twoChars As String: twoChars = vbNullString
    While counter <> theLength + 1
        theChar = Mid(jsonIn, counter, 1)
        twoChars = Mid(jsonIn, counter, 2)
        If theChar = "{" Or theChar = "[" Then
            JsonOut = JsonOut & theChar
            JsonOut = JsonOut & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
            positionIndent = positionIndent + 1
            For i = 0 To positionIndent
                JsonOut = JsonOut & Space(5)
            Next i
        ElseIf theChar = "}" Or theChar = "]" Then
            JsonOut = JsonOut & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
            positionIndent = positionIndent - 1
            For i = 0 To positionIndent
                JsonOut = JsonOut + Space(5)
            Next i
            JsonOut = JsonOut + theChar
            'For i = 0 To positionIndent
            ' JsonOut = JsonOut + Space(5)
            'Next i
        ElseIf twoChars = "]," Or twoChars = "}," Or twoChars = ",""" Then
            JsonOut = JsonOut & theChar
            JsonOut = JsonOut & Chr(13) & Chr(10)
            For i = 0 To positionIndent
                JsonOut = JsonOut + Space(5)
            Next i
        Else
            JsonOut = JsonOut + theChar
        End If
        counter = counter + 1
    Wend
    indentJsonV2 = JsonOut
End Function
```

Comment: It seems like your answer is answering the question "how to indent a JSON string in VBA?", but in the question, the string is already indented. They are more asking about how to parse and diplay a specific element inside a JSON string.

Comment: Actually, I realize that the original post didn't have indentation, but the question clearly states : "I would like to access to what I want [inside the JSON] and display it in cell"

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below example. **Import [JSON.bas](https://github.com/omegastripes/VBA-JSON-parser) module into the VBA project for JSON processing.**

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON
    Dim sState As String
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()
    Dim vResult

    ' Read JSON sample from file C:\Test\sample.json
    sJSONString = ReadTextFile("C:\Test\sample.json", 0)
    ' Parse JSON sample
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    If sState = "Error" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid JSON"
        End
    End If
    ' Convert raw JSON to 2d array and output to worksheet #1
    JSON.ToArray vJSON, aData, aHeader
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    ' Flatten JSON
    JSON.Flatten vJSON, vResult
    ' Convert flattened JSON to 2d array and output to worksheet #2
    JSON.ToArray vResult, aData, aHeader
    With Sheets(2)
        .Cells.Delete
        .Cells.WrapText = False
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Completed"

End Sub

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize(1, UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Function ReadTextFile(sPath As String, lFormat As Long) As String

    ' lFormat -2 - System default, -1 - Unicode, 0 - ASCII
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(sPath, 1, False, lFormat)
        ReadTextFile = ""
        If Not .AtEndOfStream Then ReadTextFile = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With

End Function
```

BTW, the similar approach applied [in other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a2165759%20is%3aanswer%20json.bas).